# CKEditor divarea plugin doesn`t work correctly on iOs device with Safari 8

Tags: javascript, css, safari, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I use **CKeditor** (vers.4.5.1) with **divarea** plugin and "**minimalist**" skin.
it is necessary to have ability to change font size for selected text.

When I open my page in iPad with iOS 8 in Safari, then I select the text and click to FontSize menu, it appears and after I click to particular font size no text size is updated, but cursor caret returns to some position which I don`t use before.
It is worthy of note that I can use chosen font size from last step just typing the text after it.

So, `I do not understand how can I fix it in order to change the font size of selected text, because I do not find the same questions about it.`

P.S. the common issue that `impossible to apply any text formatting from Select Boxes in iPad with Safari`.
Just open the next page:http://ckeditor.com/demo#div in iPad with Safari browser and trying to apply Styles to some word in text.

Comment: This seems a bug that you should report to them, not a question about your code.

Comment: Create the ticket for this bug: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13573#ticket